# C# - String comparison is false, despite my checking

Tags: c#

I am working with basic Windows Forms C#, and the code for the button "Voltar" and the click is shown below. The string does get the right string "Voltar" but when it gets to the if, it never enters that block of code.
The MessageBoxes: It always shows "Outside Voltar" with the string "b1" in the title, so i can see it's the right string, but then jumps right to the "Really past Voltar".

```
Button voltar = new Button();
        voltar.Text = " Voltar";
        voltar.Location = new Point(200, 430);
        voltar.Size = new Size(75, 25);
        voltar.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        voltar.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        voltar.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Controls.Add(voltar);
        voltar.Click += new EventHandler(submit_click);
    }

    public void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Boolean flag = true;

        String b1 = ((Button)sender).Text;
        MessageBox.Show("Outside Voltar", b1, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if (b1 == "Voltar")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inside Voltar", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            this.Close();
            app1.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("Past Voltar", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.
       }
MessageBox.Show("Really past Voltar", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: `" Voltar"` != `"Voltar"`, you have leading blank in the first one.

Comment: I hate myself. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Suggestion. Declare constant variable with text you want. Set button text and use in comparison that variable. This will prevent problems like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a space in its text:

```
voltar.Text = " Voltar";
---------------^------------  //here
```

so the following line is not true:

```
if (b1 == "Voltar")
```

You should do one of these:

1-  `voltar.Text = "Voltar";`

2-   `if (b1 == " Voltar")`

3-   `if (b1.Trim() == "Voltar")`

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus.
You are absolutely right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PabloSylar you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra space in your string.  Easiest way to deal with whitespace is to trim your strings

```
string b1 = ((Button)sender).Text.Trim();
```